# add hours with integer numbers 4 digits (hour1 +hour2) without datetime C#

Tags: c#

im trying something simply but i'm stack  with next:
i got 2 numbers from console with 4 digits, and it suposes to add itself like hours. Task says: add 2 hours (by user both hours) i need it works like this

1030 + 0825 = **8:55**

hour1 1033 + hour2 0835 = **19:08**

I know this is easy with DateTime. However, I cannot use DateTime here. The solution should use aritmetic operations like my current code.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int horaEntrada, horaEntrada2, hora, minut, hora2,minut2, sumamin,sumahora;
        Console.WriteLine("Entra hora");
        horaEntrada = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Entra hora 2");
        horaEntrada2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        hora = horaEntrada / 100;
        minut = horaEntrada  % 100;
        hora2 = horaEntrada2 / 100;
        minut2 = horaEntrada2 % 100;
        sumamin = minut + minut2;
        sumahora = hora + hora2;
        if (sumamin > 59)
            {
                sumamin = 0;
                if (sumahora > 23) sumahora = 0;
                else sumahora++;
            }
            else sumamin++;


        Console.WriteLine($"la suma de las horas {horaEntrada} + {horaEntrada2} es {sumahora}:{sumamin}");
    }
```

Comment: What is the isssue you're having with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

Ok So I tried this myself and I ran into 2 problems with your code:

**Problems**

- When the minutes are above 60, you reset the minutes to 0 instead of substracting 60 from it. So I changed `sumamin = 0;` to `sumamin -= 60;`

```cs
if (sumamin >= 60)
{
  sumamin -= 60;
  if (sumahora > 23)
    sumahora = 0;
  else sumahora++;
}
```

The second thing is that if the remaining minutes are under 10, it will not add the 0 so I did this: This will add a 0 in front to get the right format.

```cs
string resultMin = "0";
  if (sumamin.ToString().Length == 1) {
    resultMin = $"0{sumamin.ToString()}";
}
```

Hope it helps :))

Comment: If this solution helped you, please upvote so it can help other people too!